# Loop through each table on javascrape webpage with VBA macro

Tags: json, vba, excel, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to webscrape multiple tables from a website. So far I have built an excel VBA macro to do this. I also figured out how to get all the data when it is on multiple pages in the website. For instance, if I have 1000 results but 50 are displayed on each page. The problem is that I have the same 5 tables on multiple pages because each table has 1000 results.

My code can only loop through each page for 1 table. I also have written code to grab each table, but I cannot figure out how to do that for each of the 50 search results (each page).

How can I loop through multiple tables and click the next page in the process to capture all the data?

```
Sub ETFDat()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strText As String
    Dim jj As Long
    Dim hBody As Object
    Dim hTR As Object
    Dim hTD As Object
    Dim tb As Object
    Dim bb As Object
    Dim Tr As Object
    Dim Td As Object
    Dim ii As Long
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim hTable As Object
    Dim y As Long
    Dim z As Long
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    y = 1   'Column A in Excel
    z = 1   'Row 1 in Excel
    Sheets("Fund Basics").Activate
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Clear

    IE.navigate "http://www.etf.com/channels/smart-beta-etfs/channels/smart-       beta-etfs?qt-tabs=0#qt-tabs" ', , , , "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" & vbCrLf
    Do While IE.busy: DoEvents: Loop
    Do While IE.ReadyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    Set doc = IE.document
    Set hTable = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")    '.GetElementByID("tablePerformance")
    ii = 1
    Do While ii <= 17
        For Each tb In hTable
            Set hBody = tb.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
            For Each bb In hBody
                Set hTR = bb.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                For Each Tr In hTR
                    Set hTD = Tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                    y = 1 ' Resets back to column A
                    For Each Td In hTD
                        ws.Cells(z, y).Value = Td.innerText
                        y = y + 1
                    Next Td
                    DoEvents
                    z = z + 1
                Next Tr
                Exit For
            Next bb
            Exit For
        Next tb
        With doc
            Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("a")
            For Each e In elems
                If (e.getAttribute("id") = "nextPage") Then
                    e.Click
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next e
        End With
        ii = ii + 1
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:05"))
    Loop

    MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Is the question how can I do this in VBA or how can I do this? I would recommend a javascript approach rather than trying to use VBA for this purpose. You could easily traverse the database and navigate along pages in a javascript (in the form of a browser extension) code and convert to excel friendly output.

Comment: @SummerDeveloper Thanks for the tip but I want to see if this can be done in Excel. I feel like I am very close..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the example showing how the data could be retrieved from the website using XHRs and JSON parsing, it consists of several steps.

1. Retrieve the data.

I looked into a little with XHRs using Chrome Developer Tools Network tab.
Most relevant data I found is JSON string returned by GET XHR from http://www.etf.com/etf-finder-channel-tag/Smart-Beta%20ETFs/-aum/50/50/1 after I clicked the next page button:

[image: GET XHR]

The response has the following structure [for single row item](http://www.etf.com/etf-finder-channel-tag/Smart-Beta%20ETFs/-aum/0/1/1):

```json
[
  {
    "productId": 576,
    "fund": "iShares Russell 1000 Value ETF",
    "ticker": "IWD",
    "inceptionDate": "2000-05-22",
    "launchDate": "2000-05-22",
    "hasSegmentReport": "true",
    "genericReport": "false",
    "hasReport": "true",
    "fundsInSegment": 20,
    "economicDevelopment": "Developed Markets",
    "totalRows": 803,
    "fundBasics": {
      "issuer": "<a href='/channels/blackrock-etfs' alt='BlackRock'>BlackRock</a>",
      "expenseRatio": {
        "value": 20
      },
      "aum": {
        "value": 36957230250
      },
      "spreadPct": {
        "value": 0.000094
      },
      "segment": "Equity: U.S. - Large Cap Value"
    },
    "performance": {
      "priceTrAsOf": "2017-02-27",
      "priceTr1Mo": {
        "value": 0.031843
      },
      "priceTr3Mo": {
        "value": 0.070156
      },
      "priceTr1Yr": {
        "value": 0.281541
      },
      "priceTr3YrAnnualized": {
        "value": 0.099171
      },
      "priceTr5YrAnnualized": {
        "value": 0.13778
      },
      "priceTr10YrAnnualized": {
        "value": 0.061687
      }
    },
    "analysis": {
      "analystPick": null,
      "opportunitiesList": null,
      "letterGrade": "A",
      "efficiencyScore": 97.977103,
      "tradabilityScore": 99.260541,
      "fitScore": 84.915658,
      "leveragedFactor": null,
      "exposureReset": null,
      "avgDailyDollarVolume": 243848188.037378,
      "avgDailyShareVolume": 2148400.688889,
      "spread": {
        "value": 0.010636
      },
      "fundClosureRisk": "Low"
    },
    "fundamentals": {
      "dividendYield": {
        "value": 0.021543
      },
      "equity": {
        "pe": 27.529645,
        "pb": 1.964124
      },
      "fixedIncome": {
        "duration": null,
        "creditQuality": null,
        "ytm": {
          "value": null
        }
      }
    },
    "classification": {
      "assetClass": "Equity",
      "strategy": "Value",
      "region": "North America",
      "geography": "U.S.",
      "category": "Size and Style",
      "focus": "Large Cap",
      "niche": "Value",
      "inverse": "false",
      "leveraged": "false",
      "etn": "false",
      "selectionCriteria": "Multi-Factor",
      "weightingScheme": "Multi-Factor",
      "activePerSec": "false",
      "underlyingIndex": "Russell 1000 Value Index",
      "indexProvider": "Russell",
      "brand": "iShares"
    },
    "tax": {
      "legalStructure": "Open-Ended Fund",
      "maxLtCapitalGainsRate": 20,
      "maxStCapitalGainsRate": 39.6,
      "taxReporting": "1099"
    }
  }
]
```

2. The property `"totalRows": 803` specifies the total rows count. So to make data retrieving as fast as it possible, better to make the request to get the first row. As you can see from the URL, there is `../-aum/50/50/..` tail, which points sorting order, item to start from, and total items to return. Thus to get the only row it should be `http://www.etf.com/etf-finder-channel-tag/Smart-Beta%20ETFs/-aum/0/1/1`
3. Parse retrieved JSON, get the total number of rows from `totalRows` property.
4. Make another one request to get the entire table.
5. Parse the entire table JSON, convert it to 2d array and output. You can perform further processing with direct access to the array.

For the table shown below:

[image: table]

The resulting table contains 803 rows and header with columns as follows:

```
productId
fund
ticker
inceptionDate
launchDate
hasSegmentReport
genericReport
hasReport
fundsInSegment
economicDevelopment
totalRows
fundBasics_issuer
fundBasics_expenseRatio_value
fundBasics_aum_value
fundBasics_spreadPct_value
fundBasics_segment
performance_priceTrAsOf
performance_priceTr1Mo_value
performance_priceTr3Mo_value
performance_priceTr1Yr_value
performance_priceTr3YrAnnualized_value
performance_priceTr5YrAnnualized_value
performance_priceTr10YrAnnualized_value
analysis_analystPick
analysis_opportunitiesList
analysis_letterGrade
analysis_efficiencyScore
analysis_tradabilityScore
analysis_fitScore
analysis_leveragedFactor
analysis_exposureReset
analysis_avgDailyDollarVolume
analysis_avgDailyShareVolume
analysis_spread_value
analysis_fundClosureRisk
fundamentals_dividendYield_value
fundamentals_equity_pe
fundamentals_equity_pb
fundamentals_fixedIncome_duration
fundamentals_fixedIncome_creditQuality
fundamentals_fixedIncome_ytm_value
classification_assetClass
classification_strategy
classification_region
classification_geography
classification_category
classification_focus
classification_niche
classification_inverse
classification_leveraged
classification_etn
classification_selectionCriteria
classification_weightingScheme
classification_activePerSec
classification_underlyingIndex
classification_indexProvider
classification_brand
tax_legalStructure
tax_maxLtCapitalGainsRate
tax_maxStCapitalGainsRate
tax_taxReporting
```

Put the below code into VBA Project standard module:

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub GetData()

    Dim sJSONString As String
    Dim vJSON As Variant
    Dim sState As String
    Dim lRowsQty As Long
    Dim aData()
    Dim aHeader()

    ' Download and parse the only first row to get total rows qty
    sJSONString = GetXHR("http://www.etf.com/etf-finder-channel-tag/Smart-Beta%20ETFs/-aum/0/1/1")
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    lRowsQty = vJSON(0)("totalRows")
    ' Download and parse the entire data
    sJSONString = GetXHR("http://www.etf.com/etf-finder-channel-tag/Smart-Beta%20ETFs/-aum/0/" & lRowsQty & "/1")
    JSON.Parse sJSONString, vJSON, sState
    ' Convert JSON to 2d array
    JSON.ToArray vJSON, aData, aHeader
    ' Output
    With Sheets(1)
        .Cells.Delete
        OutputArray .Cells(1, 1), aHeader
        Output2DArray .Cells(2, 1), aData
        .Cells.Columns.AutoFit
    End With

End Sub

Function GetXHR(sURL As String) As String

    With CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
        .Open "GET", sURL, False
        .Send
        GetXHR = .responseText
    End With

End Function

Sub OutputArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                1, _
                UBound(aCells) - LBound(aCells) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub

Sub Output2DArray(oDstRng As Range, aCells As Variant)

    With oDstRng
        .Parent.Select
        With .Resize( _
                UBound(aCells, 1) - LBound(aCells, 1) + 1, _
                UBound(aCells, 2) - LBound(aCells, 2) + 1)
            .NumberFormat = "@"
            .Value = aCells
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

Create one more standard module, name it `JSON` and put the below code into it, this code provides JSON processing functionality:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private sBuffer As String
Private oTokens As Object
Private oRegEx As Object
Private bMatch As Boolean
Private oChunks As Object
Private oHeader As Object
Private aData() As Variant
Private i As Long

Sub Parse(ByVal sSample As String, vJSON As Variant, sState As String)

    ' Backus–Naur form JSON parser implementation based on RegEx
    ' Input:
    ' sSample - source JSON string
    ' Output:
    ' vJson - created object or array to be returned as result
    ' sState - string Object|Array|Error depending on processing

    sBuffer = sSample
    Set oTokens = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set oRegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With oRegEx ' Patterns based on specification http://www.json.org/
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = True ' Unspecified True, False, Null accepted
        .Pattern = "(?:'[^']*'|""(?:\\""|[^""])*"")(?=\s*[,\:\]\}])" ' Double-quoted string, unspecified quoted string
        Tokenize "s"
        .Pattern = "[+-]?(?:\d+\.\d*|\.\d+|\d+)(?:e[+-]?\d+)?(?=\s*[,\]\}])" ' Number, E notation number
        Tokenize "d"
        .Pattern = "\b(?:true|false|null)(?=\s*[,\]\}])" ' Constants true, false, null
        Tokenize "c"
        .Pattern = "\b[A-Za-z_]\w*(?=\s*\:)" ' Unspecified non-double-quoted property name accepted
        Tokenize "n"
        .Pattern = "\s+"
        sBuffer = .Replace(sBuffer, "") ' Remove unnecessary spaces
        .MultiLine = False
        Do
            bMatch = False
            .Pattern = "<\d+(?:[sn])>\:<\d+[codas]>" ' Object property structure
            Tokenize "p"
            .Pattern = "\{(?:<\d+p>(?:,<\d+p>)*)?\}" ' Object structure
            Tokenize "o"
            .Pattern = "\[(?:<\d+[codas]>(?:,<\d+[codas]>)*)?\]" ' Array structure
            Tokenize "a"
        Loop While bMatch
        .Pattern = "^<\d+[oa]>$" ' Top level object structure, unspecified array accepted
        If .Test(sBuffer) And oTokens.Exists(sBuffer) Then
            Retrieve sBuffer, vJSON
            sState = IIf(IsObject(vJSON), "Object", "Array")
        Else
            vJSON = Null
            sState = "Error"
        End If
    End With
    Set oTokens = Nothing
    Set oRegEx = Nothing

End Sub

Private Sub Tokenize(sType)

    Dim aContent() As String
    Dim lCopyIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim sKey As String

    With oRegEx.Execute(sBuffer)
        If .Count = 0 Then Exit Sub
        ReDim aContent(0 To .Count - 1)
        lCopyIndex = 1
        For i = 0 To .Count - 1
            With .Item(i)
                sKey = "<" & oTokens.Count & sType & ">"
                oTokens(sKey) = .Value
                aContent(i) = Mid(sBuffer, lCopyIndex, .FirstIndex - lCopyIndex + 1) & sKey
                lCopyIndex = .FirstIndex + .Length + 1
            End With
        Next
    End With
    sBuffer = Join(aContent, "") & Mid(sBuffer, lCopyIndex, Len(sBuffer) - lCopyIndex + 1)
    bMatch = True

End Sub

Private Sub Retrieve(sTokenKey, vTransfer)

    Dim sTokenValue As String
    Dim sName As String
    Dim vValue As Variant
    Dim aTokens() As String
    Dim i As Long

    sTokenValue = oTokens(sTokenKey)
    With oRegEx
        .Global = True
        Select Case Left(Right(sTokenKey, 2), 1)
            Case "o"
                Set vTransfer = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
                aTokens = Split(sTokenValue, "<")
                For i = 1 To UBound(aTokens)
                    Retrieve "<" & Split(aTokens(i), ">", 2)(0) & ">", vTransfer
                Next
            Case "p"
                aTokens = Split(sTokenValue, "<", 4)
                Retrieve "<" & Split(aTokens(1), ">", 2)(0) & ">", sName
                Retrieve "<" & Split(aTokens(2), ">", 2)(0) & ">", vValue
                If IsObject(vValue) Then
                    Set vTransfer(sName) = vValue
                Else
                    vTransfer(sName) = vValue
                End If
            Case "a"
                aTokens = Split(sTokenValue, "<")
                If UBound(aTokens) = 0 Then
                    vTransfer = Array()
                Else
                    ReDim vTransfer(0 To UBound(aTokens) - 1)
                    For i = 1 To UBound(aTokens)
                        Retrieve "<" & Split(aTokens(i), ">", 2)(0) & ">", vValue
                        If IsObject(vValue) Then
                            Set vTransfer(i - 1) = vValue
                        Else
                            vTransfer(i - 1) = vValue
                        End If
                    Next
                End If
            Case "n"
                vTransfer = sTokenValue
            Case "s"
                vTransfer = Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace( _
                    Mid(sTokenValue, 2, Len(sTokenValue) - 2), _
                    "\""", """"), _
                    "\\", "\"), _
                    "\/", "/"), _
                    "\b", Chr(8)), _
                    "\f", Chr(12)), _
                    "\n", vbLf), _
                    "\r", vbCr), _
                    "\t", vbTab)
                .Global = False
                .Pattern = "\\u[0-9a-fA-F]{4}"
                Do While .Test(vTransfer)
                    vTransfer = .Replace(vTransfer, ChrW(("&H" & Right(.Execute(vTransfer)(0).Value, 4)) * 1))
                Loop
            Case "d"
                vTransfer = Evaluate(sTokenValue)
            Case "c"
                Select Case LCase(sTokenValue)
                    Case "true"
                        vTransfer = True
                    Case "false"
                        vTransfer = False
                    Case "null"
                        vTransfer = Null
                End Select
        End Select
    End With

End Sub

Function Serialize(vJSON As Variant) As String

    Set oChunks = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    SerializeElement vJSON, ""
    Serialize = Join(oChunks.Items(), "")
    Set oChunks = Nothing

End Function

Private Sub SerializeElement(vElement As Variant, ByVal sIndent As String)

    Dim aKeys() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With oChunks
        Select Case VarType(vElement)
            Case vbObject
                If vElement.Count = 0 Then
                    .Item(.Count) = "{}"
                Else
                    .Item(.Count) = "{" & vbCrLf
                    aKeys = vElement.Keys
                    For i = 0 To UBound(aKeys)
                        .Item(.Count) = sIndent & vbTab & """" & aKeys(i) & """" & ": "
                        SerializeElement vElement(aKeys(i)), sIndent & vbTab
                        If Not (i = UBound(aKeys)) Then .Item(.Count) = ","
                        .Item(.Count) = vbCrLf
                    Next
                    .Item(.Count) = sIndent & "}"
                End If
            Case Is >= vbArray
                If UBound(vElement) = -1 Then
                    .Item(.Count) = "[]"
                Else
                    .Item(.Count) = "[" & vbCrLf
                    For i = 0 To UBound(vElement)
                        .Item(.Count) = sIndent & vbTab
                        SerializeElement vElement(i), sIndent & vbTab
                        If Not (i = UBound(vElement)) Then .Item(.Count) = "," 'sResult = sResult & ","
                        .Item(.Count) = vbCrLf
                    Next
                    .Item(.Count) = sIndent & "]"
                End If
            Case vbInteger, vbLong
                .Item(.Count) = vElement
            Case vbSingle, vbDouble
                .Item(.Count) = Replace(vElement, ",", ".")
            Case vbNull
                .Item(.Count) = "null"
            Case vbBoolean
                .Item(.Count) = IIf(vElement, "true", "false")
            Case Else
                .Item(.Count) = """" & _
                    Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(Replace(vElement, _
                        "\", "\\"), _
                        """", "\"""), _
                        "/", "\/"), _
                        Chr(8), "\b"), _
                        Chr(12), "\f"), _
                        vbLf, "\n"), _
                        vbCr, "\r"), _
                        vbTab, "\t") & _
                    """"
        End Select
    End With

End Sub

Function ToString(vJSON As Variant) As String

    Select Case VarType(vJSON)
        Case vbObject, Is >= vbArray
            Set oChunks = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
            ToStringElement vJSON, ""
            oChunks.Remove 0
            ToString = Join(oChunks.Items(), "")
            Set oChunks = Nothing
        Case vbNull
            ToString = "Null"
        Case vbBoolean
            ToString = IIf(vJSON, "True", "False")
        Case Else
            ToString = CStr(vJSON)
    End Select

End Function

Private Sub ToStringElement(vElement As Variant, ByVal sIndent As String)

    Dim aKeys() As Variant
    Dim i As Long

    With oChunks
        Select Case VarType(vElement)
            Case vbObject
                If vElement.Count = 0 Then
                    .Item(.Count) = "''"
                Else
                    .Item(.Count) = vbCrLf
                    aKeys = vElement.Keys
                    For i = 0 To UBound(aKeys)
                        .Item(.Count) = sIndent & aKeys(i) & ": "
                        ToStringElement vElement(aKeys(i)), sIndent & vbTab
                        If Not (i = UBound(aKeys)) Then .Item(.Count) = vbCrLf
                    Next
                End If
            Case Is >= vbArray
                If UBound(vElement) = -1 Then
                    .Item(.Count) = "''"
                Else
                    .Item(.Count) = vbCrLf
                    For i = 0 To UBound(vElement)
                        .Item(.Count) = sIndent & i & ": "
                        ToStringElement vElement(i), sIndent & vbTab
                        If Not (i = UBound(vElement)) Then .Item(.Count) = vbCrLf
                    Next
                End If
            Case vbNull
                .Item(.Count) = "Null"
            Case vbBoolean
                .Item(.Count) = IIf(vElement, "True", "False")
            Case Else
                .Item(.Count) = CStr(vElement)
        End Select
    End With

End Sub

Sub ToArray(vJSON As Variant, aRows() As Variant, aHeader() As Variant)

    ' Input:
    ' vJSON - Array or Object which contains rows data
    ' Output:
    ' aData - 2d array representing JSON data
    ' aHeader - 1d array of property names

    Dim sName As Variant

    Set oHeader = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Select Case VarType(vJSON)
        Case vbObject
            If vJSON.Count > 0 Then
                ReDim aData(0 To vJSON.Count - 1, 0 To 0)
                oHeader("#") = 0
                i = 0
                For Each sName In vJSON
                    aData(i, 0) = "#" & sName
                    ToArrayElement vJSON(sName), ""
                    i = i + 1
                Next
            Else
                ReDim aData(0 To 0, 0 To 0)
            End If
        Case Is >= vbArray
            If UBound(vJSON) >= 0 Then
                ReDim aData(0 To UBound(vJSON), 0 To 0)
                For i = 0 To UBound(vJSON)
                    ToArrayElement vJSON(i), ""
                Next
            Else
                ReDim aData(0 To 0, 0 To 0)
            End If
        Case Else
            ReDim aData(0 To 0, 0 To 0)
            aData(0, 0) = ToString(vJSON)
    End Select
    aHeader = oHeader.Keys()
    Set oHeader = Nothing
    aRows = aData
    Erase aData

End Sub

Private Sub ToArrayElement(vElement As Variant, sFieldName As String)

    Dim sName As Variant
    Dim j As Long

    Select Case VarType(vElement)
        Case vbObject ' collection of objects
            For Each sName In vElement
                ToArrayElement vElement(sName), sFieldName & IIf(sFieldName = "", "", "_") & sName
            Next
        Case Is >= vbArray  ' collection of arrays
            For j = 0 To UBound(vElement)
                ToArrayElement vElement(j), sFieldName & IIf(sFieldName = "", "", "_") & "#" & j
            Next
        Case Else
            If Not oHeader.Exists(sFieldName) Then
                oHeader(sFieldName) = oHeader.Count
                If UBound(aData, 2) < oHeader.Count - 1 Then ReDim Preserve aData(0 To UBound(aData, 1), 0 To oHeader.Count - 1)
            End If
            j = oHeader(sFieldName)
            aData(i, j) = ToString(vElement)
    End Select

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried useful the original question and found little bug that I fixed

**The answer to you question is to**

1 loop on Doc elements **until** next page link is found, and you to

2 set/reset the doc var to avoid the Doc lost

```
Do
    Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop

    Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Set doc = IE.document

    ....
 Loop While nextPageFound   'exit if "next page" not found
```

when following the next page hyper link, during loop on Doc elements.

And then I added the

3 split of Table Header and Body (if exist) for 1st row field name set

4 RESCUE of cell value from specific class by name cell against simple td.innerText

5 loop on doc for link search until NextPageFound using

```
e.getAttribute("title") instead id=nextPage
```

6 use of a SetUp sheet with parameters to customize the script with url and destination data sheet

```
strUrl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup").Range("b1").Value
strDestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup").Range("b2").Value
```

And here is the VBA function revisited:

```
Sub ETFDatNew()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim i As Long
    Dim strText As String
    Dim jj As Long
    Dim hBody As Object
    Dim hTR As Object
    Dim hTD As Object
    Dim tb As Object
    Dim bb As Object
    Dim Tr As Object
    Dim Td As Object
    Dim ii As Long
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim hTable As Object
    Dim y As Long
    Dim z As Long
    Dim wb As Excel.Workbook
    Dim ws As Excel.Worksheet

    Set wb = Excel.ActiveWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.ActiveSheet
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
    IE.Visible = True
    y = 1   'Column A in Excel
    z = 1   'Row 1 in Excel
    

    '6 I used a SetUp sheet with parameters to customize the script with url and destination data sheet

    strUrl = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup").Range("b1").Value
    strDestSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Setup").Range("b2").Value
    
  
    Sheets(strDestSheet).Activate ' Destination sheet
    
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Clear

    'IE.navigate "http://halleyweb.com/c058057/mc/mc_p_ricerca.php" ', , , , "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" & vbCrLf
    IE.navigate strUrl
    
    ii = 1
    nextPageFound = True  'set to init scope var / settato per iniziare il loop
    Do '1) loop until nextPageFound instead of '' ii <= 17 Or
    
        '2 set/reset of doc to avoid doc lost after next page link click (see below)
        Do While IE.Busy: DoEvents: Loop
        Do While IE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
        Set doc = IE.document

        ' all tables or single one by Id
        Set hTable = doc.getElementsByTagName("table")   'or by .getElementById("table-albo-pretorio")

        For Each tb In hTable
            '3) splitting header vs body for 1st row field name search
            'tHeader
            If z = 1 Then
                Set hBody = tb.getElementsByTagName("thead")
                For Each bb In hBody
                    Set hTR = bb.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                    For Each Tr In hTR
                        Set hTD = Tr.getElementsByTagName("th") 'header th
                        y = 1 ' Resets back to column A
                        For Each Th In hTD
                            ws.Cells(z, y).Value = Th.innerText
                            y = y + 1
                        Next Th
                        DoEvents
                        z = z + 1
                    Next Tr
                    Exit For
                Next bb
            End If
            
            'tBody
            Set hBody = tb.getElementsByTagName("tbody")
            For Each bb In hBody
                Set hTR = bb.getElementsByTagName("tr")
                For Each Tr In hTR
                    Set hTD = Tr.getElementsByTagName("td")
                    y = 1 ' Resets back to column A
                    For Each Td In hTD

                        '4) RESCUE cell value from td.innerText against specific class name cell
                        'ws.Cells(z, y).Value = Td.innerText
                        
                        If CBool(Td.getElementsByClassName("tablesaw-cell-content").Length) Then 'there is at least 1
                        'use the first
                            ws.Cells(z, y).Value = Td.getElementsByClassName("tablesaw-cell-content")(0).innerText
                        End If
                    
                        y = y + 1 'colonna successiva /next col
                    
                    Next Td
                    DoEvents
                    z = z + 1 'riga successiva /next row
                Next Tr
                Exit For
            Next bb
            Exit For
        Next tb
        '5 looping on doc for link search until NextPageFound using e.getAttribute("title") instead id=nextPage

        With doc 'ricerca dei link
            Set elems = .getElementsByTagName("a")
            nextPageFound = False   ' si predispone per concludere nel caso non sia presente una pagina successiva
            For Each e In elems
                If (e.getAttribute("title") = "Pagina successiva") Then ' alla ricerca di link con title="Pagina successiva" / instead of id=nextPage
                    e.Click
                    nextPageFound = True ' trovata pagina successiva /found next page
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next e
        End With
        
        ii = ii + 1
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:01"))
    Loop While nextPageFound   ' conclude nel caso non sia stato trovato il link Pagina successiva / exit if not found
        
    IE.Quit
    Set IE = Nothing
    Application.StatusBar = ""
    MsgBox "Estrazione completata" ' completed

End Sub
```